# This algorithm does not have a quadratic run time right?

Tags: algorithm, constraints, code-analysis

I recently had an interview and was given a small problem that I was to code up.

The problem was basically find duplicates in an array of length n, using constant space in O(n). Each element is in the range 1-(n-1) and guaranteed to be a duplicate. This is what I came up with:

```
public int findDuplicate(int[] vals) {
    int indexSum=0;
    int valSum=0;   
    for (int i=0; i< vals.length; i++) {
         indexSum += i;
         valSum += vals[i];
    }
    return valSum - indexSum;
}
```

Then we got into a discussion about the runtime of this algorithm. A sum of series from 0 -> n = (n^2 + n)/2 which is quadratic. However, isn't the algorithm O(n) time? The number of operations are bound by the length of the array right?

What am I missing? Is this algorithm O(n^2)?

Comment: I am curious why would 
you think this is O(n^2)? :)

Comment: It was the impression I was left with from the interviewer. It was quite bizarre as he seemed to imply it was quadratic and then ended the interview abruptly. It left me confused and I'm sure it was just a miscommunication.

Comment: Am I missing something or is indeed your solution to the problem not right (or the definition of the problem incomplete). If I would have an array of N elements, I would use a hash map with the value as key and a counter as value. It would require 1 pass to initialize the map, another pass to set all the counters right, and a last pass trough the map to extract the duplicates list. That would mean 3 passes in total, which would make it O(n). Maybe that's the reason the interview ended abruptly

Comment: @John Paul: He has to use constant space.

Comment: But the problem doesn't seem to be solved in constant space. Just in order to keep sum of series, which is (n^2+n)/2, you need log((n^2+n)/2) bits, which is O(logn). Maybe point of the interview was somehow to discuss all the complexity concerns.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that the sum of the integers from `0` to `n` is `O(n^2)` is irrelevant here.

Yes you run through the loop exactly `O(n)` times.

The big question is, what order of complexity are you assuming on addition?

If `O(1)` then yeah, this is linear. Most people will assume that addition is `O(1)`.

But iwhat if addition is actually `O(b)` (`b` is bits, and in our case `b = log n`)? If you are going to assume this, then this algorithm is actually `O(n * log n)` (adding `n` numbers, each needs `log n` bits to represent).

Again, most people assume that addition is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithms researchers have standardized on the *unit-cost RAM* model, where words are Theta(log n) bits and operations on words are Theta(1) time. An alternative model where operations on words are Theta(log n) time is not used any more because it's ridiculous to have a RAM that [can't recognize palindromes in linear time](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=44492).

Your algorithm clearly runs in time O(n) and extra space O(1), since convention is for the default unit of space to be the word. Your interviewer may have been worried about overflow, but your algorithm works fine if addition and subtraction are performed modulo any number M ≥ n, as would be the case for two's complement.

tl;dr Whatever your interviewer's problem was is imaginary or rooted in an improper understanding of the conventions of theoretical computer science.

Comment: See also this post: http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2009/05/shaving-logs-with-unit-cost.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes the algorithm is linear*. The result of `valSum` doesn't affect the running time. Take it to extreme, the function

```
int f(int[] vals) {
   return vals.length * vals.length;
}
```

gives n<sup>2</sup> in 1 multiplication. Obviously this doesn't mean `f` is O(n<sup>2</sup>) ;)

<sup>(*: assuming addition is O(1))</sup>

Comment: Not so fast. Grade-school multiplication algorithm is `O(n^2)` (`n` is number of bits). There are faster algorithms, but none is `O(1)`.

Comment: @Jason: Typically `int` is a 32 or 64-bit integer, not a Big-Int.

Comment: When you implement on a computer, yeah sure. Not when you study the algorithm from a theoretical perspective.

Comment: Another way to say it is, if you are going to assume that we are only dealing with a bounded space of int, then this problem is `O(1)` because the time to run the algorithm on all inputs is bounded above by the time to run the algorithm on an input of size "max int". But then there's all sorts of nasty overflow issues with this implementation etc. So we just abstract away that stuff.

Comment: @Jason: Yes I understand, but I'd consider that as impractical. If you need to handle Big-Int length when OP's solution is wrong because to store `indexSum` and `valSum` and `i` you need O(log N) extra bits while the question requires O(1) space.

Comment: Sorry, but when people study algorithms they study them from a theoretical perspective. Factoring integers is `O(1)` if you only worry about what can fit into `int` or `long`.

Comment: I agree with Jason; it is said all numbers are between `1` and `n-1`, so you cannot limit yourself to 32-bit integers as you wouldn't even be able to read the value. As you take into account size of the table, you have to take into account size of a single cell (which is in relation with `n`).

Comment: @tomasz: OK you're right. In that case the input size would be "O(n log n)" since you need O(log n) bits to store an integer. So OP's algorithm *is* linear because it takes O(n log n) = O(InputSize) time. (Also, multiplication would take O((log n)^2) = O(W(InputSize)^2) = O((log InputSize)^2).)

Comment: @KennyTM: Sounds very reasonable and I could agree with this, however, I'm not sure I'm competent enough to give the answer. It probably depends on original problem (was the complexity bounded by input size or just length of array?). What concerns me more is space limitation; it looks like we need `O(n)` space to keep the sum.

Comment: @tomasz: True. If we invoke Big-Int length, then to store `valSum` one needs to have to spare O(log(n^2)) = O(log(n)) = O(log InputSize) space, as in my reply to @Jason. So OP's solution would pass in a job interview, but would fail in a PhD interview :)

Comment: @KennyTM It's log(n), you're right. Not sure about interview though, maybe the whole point was to come up with such a solution and than discuss all the complexity concerns. It doesn't fit PhD for sure :)

Comment: @KennyTM: Well, that would be correct if he were asking about the order of complexity in terms of the size of the input in bits, but he appears to be asking about the order of complexity in terms of the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You work on each on `n` cells one time each. Linear time.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of i from i=0 to n is n*(n+1)/2 which is bounded by `n^2` but that has nothing to do with running time... that's just the closed form of the summation.

The running time of your algorithm is linear, `O(n)`, where n is the number of elements in your array (assuming the addition operation is a constant time operation, `O(1)`).

I hope this helps.
Hristo